# Accessing System Databases/Tables using LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

Right now I have an [SSIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services) package that runs every morning and gives me a report on the number of packages that failed or succeeded from the day before. The information for these packages is contained partly within the `sysjobs` table (a system table) within the `msdb` database (a system database) in [SQL Server 2005](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2005).

When trying to move the package to a C# executable (mostly to gain better formatting over the email that gets sent out), I wasn't able to find a way to create a dbml file that allowed me to access these tables through [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query). I tried to look for any properties that would make these tables visible, but I haven't had much luck.

Is this possible with [LINQ to SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_SQL_.28formerly_called_DLINQ.29)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you're in Server Explorer, you can make them visible this way:

- Create a connection to the server you want.
- Right-click the server and choose Change View > Object Type.
- You should now see System Tables and User Tables.  You should see sysjobs there, and you can easily drag it onto a .dbml surface.

Comment: When I expand the System Tables I don't see any sysjobs there, how to display sysjobs or any reason why it doesn't show???

Comment: @Ash, are you sure that the user/password you're using has permission to see those?  If you're using integrated security, are you sure _your_ user has permission to see those?

Comment: It is a local database and I am the db owner and still don't see it, not sure if I need other permissions to see it

Answer (score 0):

It may not be available in the designer, but why not just add it to the DBML file itself?