# SQL - LINQ2SQL - Accessing sys.table

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql

I have Googled this without any success.

Here is the SQL query and I wish to turn it into LINQ2SQL.

```
SELECT c.name FROM sys.tables t JOIN sys.columns c ON t.Object_ID = c.Object_ID WHERE t.Name = 'Address'
```

At first I tried accessing just the sys.table like this:

```
from n in _db.sys.table where n.table select n

_db = new DBDataContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DATABASE"].ConnectionString);
```

I am however receiving the following error - Cannot resolve symbol 'sys'

Can you even do this in LINQ2SQL?

Thanks in advance.

Clare :-)

Comment: Might [this help][1]? (basically, you can't reference the sys. objects as you have done, but you can add the sys tables to the dbml). Hey, my answer has become a comment! no wonder I never get any points (well, that and providing wrong answers).


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54222/linq-to-sql-accessing-system-databases-tables

Comment: Thanks, was hoping I didn't have to do that, but it has worked so I'm happy :-).

Answer (score 0):

You could also develop a View to access sys.tables, and map that View...

Answer (score -1):

A stored proc can work well too - you just drag it in and it creates a new type with all the right in and out parameters.