# LINQ to SQL Table Names

Tags: sql, linq

I want get my tables name with LINQ

For Example I Have DB with 5 Table and i want show my tables name in a listBox

Then whith a Query I Add a Table then try again, now we have ListBox With 6 Items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Linq to SQL DataContext already has the table names: [`context.Mapping.GetTables()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.metamodel.gettables)

Comment: It,s Right! Im new to LINQ :)

Comment: It most scenarios, this is what you'll want; however, this will only get the tables that are mapped, it won't automatically pick up a new table that you've created, without recompiling (or otherwise updating your mapping).

Comment: How i can Update My mapping Programmicaly ?!
I want create table Runtime and then use it.

Comment: If you add a table that the DataContext knows about, it *should* show up in the Mapping.

Answer (score 4):

You can add the `sys.tables` or `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` view to your design surface, and query it for the table names.

To do that, in your Server Explorer, right click on the server, and choose *Object Type* or *Schema* from the *Change Type* menu (per *[Linq to SQL - Accessing System Databases/Tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54222/2688)*).  You can then find these under the System Views item.